# How can I keep track of each users disliked items and exclude them from the result in an efficient way

Tags: elasticsearch, data-modeling, modeling

I have a question about how a specific use case should be modelled in ElasticSearch.

I have an application where users can search for recommendations with several parameters and like/dislike each returned recommendation item. As it is now, recommendations that the user previously has disliked might show up again. So the question is; How can I keep track of each users disliked recommendations and exclude them from the result in an efficient way?

So if user1 search for recommendations and the result is:
rec1, rec2, rec3, rec4, rec5

If user1 then dislikes rec1 and rec2, and does the same search again, the result should be:
rec3, rec4, rec5

I’m aware that the search params should then contain the searching user’s id, and that some kind of user disliked recommendation list should be maintained in elastic search, but is that efficient enough if the application gains a large user base with many recommendation dislikes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can certainly index "user" documents and keep a list of dislikes in an array. However, having ES automatically "join" to that user's document and modify its search parameters based on a field in that document is not possible.

You're best bet is to load the user's preferences into a session in the application that sits between the user and ES. From there, you'll have to modify any queries that go to ES to exclude items that the user has disliked.

Comment: I have read about the parent/child relationship and I think it will work for my use-case. The idea is to have a type 'recommendation' as parent, and a type 'dislike' as child. Dislikes are then related to each recommendation, and can be added/removed without re-indexing the entire recommendation document, i.e. when a user dislikes a recommendation a dislike containing the user's id is created with the disliked recommendation as parent. When searching, I can filter all the recommendations that does not have a dislike child with the given user id. What do you think about this performance wise?

Comment: Maybe, that's getting pretty detailed into your model so I'm not going to comment too much. I will say that parent child relationships work best when there are a limited number of parent vs children. I'll also add that reindexing a document is pretty cheap.

Comment: Ok. In the case where dislikes are children to each disliked recommendation. Would it fit to have e.g. 200.000 recommendations/parents, and each of these recommendations could then have x amount of dislikes (could potentially be equal to the amount of users e.g. 500.000)